# Note: To send record assignment notifications, an SMTP server must be configured in Email Settings

Tags: javascript, php, phpmailer, sugarcrm, suitecrm

[image]

I recently upgraded my wampp server and use new update suitcrm version.

When I check the log, this appears:

> [****Note: To send record assignment notifications, an SMTP server must be configured in Email Settings.****]

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your SMTP.

Go to

1. Admin
2. Outbound email

And setup your preferred SMTP, maybe use your provider *yahoo/outlook/gmail(requires some settings modification)

Comment: but is not working always say............show troubleshooting problem......and php mail() is not working.....plZ help me.

Comment: how to make new user without using mail configuration......plz help me.

Comment: first, use a regular email client (thunderbird) to test that from your machine you can connect to google SMTP server. once you are 100% sure try those login details on the CRM

Comment: @PradeepSharma - I think you have to put some more effort on your part otherwise you will never get help from an online community. 
If you can't configure an email account with google at hand you are not doing enough.

Comment: can you post the suitcrm.log when you click on send test email?